# Configure SMTP host using YAML file in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp

I am trying to configure an SMTP host for my Spring boot application.

I have this code in my `application-dev.yml` file:

```
 mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 465
    username: myemail@gmail.com
    password: mypassword
```

However, when I am trying to send an email I get this exception:

```
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to 
SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, 
port: 465, response: -1
```

Also, I have generated this code with JHipster and I am not sure whether I should modify something else or this is enough to configure a SMTP host.

After changing the port to 587, I am getting this:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: 
Failed messages:    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue 
a STARTTLS command first. jm6sm60863600wjb.27 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 14):

I made the following changes and now it works fine:

```
 mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: mymail@gmail.com
    password: mypassword
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls.enable: true
        ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

Answer (score 5):

I have used following YAML configuration for sending mail via Gmail

```
spring:
  mail:
    default-encoding: UTF-8
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    username: <Gmail username>
    password: <Gmail password>
    port: 587
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
    protocol: smtp
    test-connection: false
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you got the port wrong. I believe it's `587`

**Updated**

Now we need to set StartTLS

add

```
mail:
  host: smtp.gmail.com
  port: 587
  username: myemail@gmail.com
  password: mypassword
  properties:
    starttls.enable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the conf below. It's working in my environment.

```
  mail:
    debug: false
    host: host
    port: port_number
    properties:
      mail:
        protocol: smtp
        smtp:
          ssl:
            enable: true
            trust: "*"
          auth: false
          starttls:
            enable: true
            required: false
```